# Approach for replacing forms authentication in .NET application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, iprincipal

My question is about an approach, and I am looking for tips or links to help me develop a solution.  I have an .NET 4.0 web forms application that works with Forms authentication using the aspnetdb SQL database of users and passwords.  A new feature for the application is a *new* authentication mechanism using single sign on to allow access for thousands of new users.  Essentially, when the user logs in through the new single-sign-on method, I will be able to identify them as legitimate users with a role.

So I will have something like **HttpContext.Current.Session["email_of_authenticated_user"]** (their identity) and **HttpContext.Current.Session["role_of_authenticated_user"]** (their role).

Importantly, I don't necessarily want to maintain these users and roles redundantly in the aspnetdb database which will be retired, but I *do* want to use the session objects above to allow the user to pass through the application as if they were in passing through with forms authentication.  I don't think CustomRoleProviders or CustomMemberProviders are helpful since they do not allow for creating session-level users.

So my question is how to use the session level user and role that I do have to "mimic" all the forms authentication goodness like enforcing:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Student")]
```

or

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="wilma, barney" />
</authorization>
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing `Forms Authentication` with the `SqlMembershipProvider`.

Forms authentication is the means by which ASP.NET generically authorizes and authenticates users.  It does not specify a specific implementation of how that is done.  It only provides a way that, once authenticated, the application can use those credentials throughout the app via a "ticket" system that's saved as a cookie.

Essentially, there are only two kinds of authentication in windows, Forms Authentication and Windows Authentication.  Since your new method is not Windows based, then you have to use Forms Authentication (unless you simply ignore the stuff that's built into asp.net and roll everything yourself, which is kind of stupid to do).

You might want to look into the [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351) as it provides a plugable architecture for identity, including various web based single sign-on methods.

Comment: Certainly you would be advised to keep using Forms Authentication using Cookies as they way to pass user information back and forth with the client. Use the FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(...) when you have validated a user and FormsAuthentication.SignOut() to clear it again.

Comment: I 3rd the suggestion.  Keep FormsAuthentication...you're looking to replace the authorization mechanism (i.e. SqlMembershipProvider)